# run shell script as other user, but directory stay the same

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, users

I have to run a bash script as root. But in this script, there are commands that I have to run as my normal user (he's named "ubuntu"), but when doing it I don't want the current working directory to change.

### Things that I tried, but doesn't perfectly work :

Let's say that I am in a folder : `/var/www` and that I am in super user mode.

#### -u

- `sudo -u ubuntu pwd` gives me `/var/www`, which is **nice**.
- But `sudo -u ubuntu which composer` gives me nothing, which is **bad**.

#### -i -u

- `sudo -i -u ubuntu which composer` gives me `/home/ubuntu/bin/composer` which is **nice**.
- But `sudo -i -u ubuntu pwd` gives me `/home/ubuntu` which is **bad**.

I also tried to add a -H, or -s but it doesn't help in any way.

What kind of options or tricks could I use to achieve this ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Like if you're trying to call `/home/ubuntu/bin/composer`, you could call it by the full path, `/home/ubuntu/bin/composer`.

Comment: Not exactly, cause I have to execute this script on several machines. And `composer` won't be stored at the same place every time. But on all machine, I have a user called `ubuntu` that have a command called `composer`.